# Avoiding race condition - Parallel programing

Tags: c#, wpf, parallel-processing

I'm using this function [*makeComputerMove*] with the **Task.Factory.StartNew** statement to avoid UI freeze in my WPF application.
I'm calling this function from a *while loop* and I believe I have a race condition.
I'm looking for a way to wait until the complement of the function before moving on.

```
private void makeComputerMove(PocGraph.Heuristic h, PocGraph.Player p)
{
    Node tree = null;
    TaskScheduler scheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
    CancellationToken cancelationToken = new CancellationToken();
    playLoadingStoryBoard(); 
    Task taskA = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { tree = vm.buildMovesTree(h, p); }).
        ContinueWith(w =>
        {
            showWaterMarkForComputerMove(h.ToString(), tree.BestMove.Player.ToString(), tree.BestMove.Position);
            makeComputerMove(tree.BestMove.Position, tree.BestMove.Player);
            stopLoadingStoryBoard();

        },
        cancelationToken,
        TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously, scheduler);
}
```

The While loop:

```
while (!gameOver() && !vm.Graph.hasWinner() && !vm.Graph.IsInfiniteLoop && isAIrunning)
                    {
                        vm.disableDelays = true;
                        //Black Move
                        makeComputerMove(blackHeuristic, PocGraph.Player.BLACK);

                        //Checking if someone won between turns
                        if (gameOver() || vm.Graph.hasWinner() || vm.Graph.IsInfiniteLoop)
                            break;

                        //Pause between Black -> Red
                        if (!cancelMessageBoxesAndWaiting)
                            vm.InteractivePauseInMilliSeconds(2000);

                        makeComputerMove(redHeuristic, PocGraph.Player.RED);

                        //Pause between Red -> Black
                        if (!cancelMessageBoxesAndWaiting)
                            vm.InteractivePauseInMilliSeconds(2000);
                    }
                    vm.disableDelays = false;
```

Comment: If you are on .net 4.5, you can use the async/await paradigm.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that with example/reference?

Comment: Tried googling it?  http://www.google.com/search?q=async+await

Comment: This will require me to rewrite a large portion of the code again...
Are you sure it will solve the problem?

Comment: I think so, but I don't have the time to discuss your game at length. If you have 15 minutes, consider the watching this video to see if async await is for you... http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Three-Essential-Tips-for-Async/Lucian03-TipsForAsyncThreadsAndDatabinding

Comment: I have tried the async/await paradigm, it's complicateד things,  I'm getting the error "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it." on many code lines...
Adding the .Dispatcher.Invoke() statement to solve it - make the code unreadable